# TextBox doesnt input Text

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-textinput

I am new to ReactNative and I am trying to able to write on my TextBoxes. Although, I can't input anything. This is the segment for my text input on my Signup.js

```
renderTextInput = (field) => {
const {meta: {touched, error}, label, secureTextEntry, maxLength, keyboardType, placeholder, input: {onChange, ...restInput}} = field;
return(
    <View>
        <InputText
            onChangeText={onChange}
            maxLength={maxLength}
            placeholder={placeholder}
            keyboardType={keyboardType}
            secureTextEntry={secureTextEntry}
            label={label}
            {...restInput} />
            {touched && <Text style={styles.errorText}>{error}</Text>}
        </View>
);
}

render() {
    const {handleSubmit} = this.props;
    return(
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Logo/>
            <Field 
                name="name" 
                placeholder="Insira o seu nome"
                component={this.renderTextInput} />
            <Field 
                name="email" 
                placeholder="Insira o seu email"    
                component={this.renderTextInput} />
            <Field 
                name="password" 
                placeholder="Password"
                secureTextEntry={true}
                component={this.renderTextInput} />
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit)}>
             <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Signup</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <View style={styles.signupTextCont}>
                <Text style={styles.signupText}>Ja tens uma conta?</Text>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.goBack}><Text style={styles.signupButton}> Entra</Text></TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        </View>
        )
    }
}
```

I don't understand why this is happening.
Please help me

Comment: What's `onChange`? How are you updating its value?

Comment: Doing it here: onChangeText={onChange}

Comment: ... And what *is* onChange? And thE other question.

Comment: Im pretty new to React-Native, so dont get me wrong, I watched this on a youtube video with the following link :https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9rrSa5MBWmY&t=459s

Comment: How do I update its value?

Comment: Can you show us the full code? I mean the entire component.